# Woher kommt die Unsitte, Markennamen komplett großzuschreiben?

Tags: capitalization, brand-name

Häufig begegnet es einem: Vom noch nachvollziehbaren SONY (immerhin steht es auf den Geräten auch nur in Versalien drauf) bis hin zum unsäglichen MAC (für einen Apple-Computer) wird von vielen Leuten jeder Marken- oder Firmenname konsequent komplett kaputtversaliert. Mir selbst wollte in einem Design-Nebenfach die Dozentin (eine Werberin) beibringen, dass man das so zu machen und außerdem den Markennamen stets ohne Bindestrich vom Rest eines Kompositums abzutrennen habe ("Das TEMPO Taschentuch").

Stört das nur mich? Hat das tatsächlich die Werbeindustrie verbrochen? Wie sollte man damit umgehen? Klar, Abkürzungen wie BMW sind natürlich großzuschreiben, aber wie hält man es sonst mit kreativer Großschreibung? Wie schreibe ich "iPhone"? Und am Satzanfang? Schreibe ich "ERGO Versicherung", "Ergo Versicherung", "Ergo-Versicherung", oder geh ich lieber zur Allianz?

Comment: +1 Das passiert mir vor allem im IT-Umfeld, wo es viele Dinge gibt, die in Wahrheit (rekursive) Akronyme sind. Aber Leute! Java ist kein Akronym (also nicht JAVA!!!). Es kann auch sein, dass man auf diese Weise die Schreibung in Kapitälchen imitieren möchte.

Comment: Einigermaßen relevant: [What do all CAPITAL letters typically refer to in writing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/what-do-all-capital-letters-typically-refer-to-in-writing/8678#8678) auf english.se.

Comment: Es stört nicht nur Dich. :) Es gibt kein Gesetz welches Dich zwingt irgendwie zu schreiben, insbesondere nicht falsch zu schreiben. Ipads, Uhu und Tempotaschentücher kaufe ich in Kaisers Supermarkt.

Comment: Ich verlinke immer wieder gern: [But FUNKY!!!web!!!DUDES.com is their trademark!](http://www.theslot.com/webnames.html) – bezieht sich zwar aufs Englische, lässt sich aber genausogut aufs Deutsche anwenden. Außerdem die [Regeln der **deutschen** Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Namenskonventionen#Abk.C3.BCrzungen_und_Eigennamen_mit_Abweichungen_von_den_Regeln_der_Rechtschreibung).

Answer (score 5):

Ein richtiges "Gesetz" hierfür gibt es natürlich nicht. Allerdings kenne und finde ich keine Referenz für Markennamen in Großbuchstaben. Das sollte Beleg genug dafür sein, dass die Dozentin Unrecht hat.

Markennamen werden grundsätzlich so geschrieben, wie die Marke sich selbst schreibt.

Mit einigen Ausnahmen:

- Stilisierung mit Interpunktion **kann** weggelassen werden (z. B. "Yahoo" statt "Yahoo!")
- Bei allzu kreativer Schreibweise **darf** der Markenname in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden.
- Markennamen, die mit Kleinbuchstaben beginnen, **müssen** auch so geschrieben werden (iMac)
- Markennamen, die in Großbuchstaben stilisiert werden, aber keine Abkürzungen sind, dürfen auch "normal" geschrieben werden. Hierzu ein sehr gutes Beispiel aus der Wikipedia:

  > Die Ergo Versicherungsgruppe Aktiengesellschaft (eigene Schreibweise ERGO) ...

Die Hersteller haben oftmals Hinweise, wie man ihre Marke behandeln soll:

> May be used in text as a descriptor, as long as it is followed by a proper generic term (e.g. "Android™ application"). First instance of this use should be followed by a ™ symbol.

Wenn die Schreibweise des Markennamens im Fließtext zu peinlich ist, z. B. iMac am Satzanfang, empfehle ich Anführungszeichen zu setzen oder den Satz umzuformen.

---

Ich muss einfach dazusagen, auch wenn das bloß meine *Meinung* ist, dass Marken in Großbuchstaben ziemlich hässlich aussehen. Und der Leser (ich), leicht den Eindruck kriegen kann, dass er angeschrien wird.

> "Unsere Plattform wird mit Hilfe von ECLIPSE gewartet."
> "Wow! Danke für die Warnung!"

Comment: `Markennamen werden grundsätzlich so geschrieben, wie die Marke sich selbst schreibt.` - wer sagt das? Der Duden? Insbesondere vor dem Hintergrund, dass sich Marken nicht selbst schreiben ist die Aussage bemerkenswert.

Comment: "Keine Referenz" als Beleg zu werten ist natürlich etwas gewagt (was nicht heißt, dass ich dem widerspreche). Für die erwähnten Regeln wären Belege schön.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hätte das besser formulieren können: Markennamen werden (tatsächlich, in der Regel, offenbar) so geschrieben, wie sie von den Firmen die sie besitzen geschrieben werden. MusiKk: was ohne Belege behauptet werden kann, kann ohne Belege verworfen werden. :) Was Referenzen für meine Empfehlungen angeht, nun, das macht wie gesagt jeder anders. Ich halte mich normalerweise, wie viele Andere (wenn auch unwissend), an Wikipedias Manual of Style: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Trademarks

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo: Das sind aber die Regeln, die sich Wikipedia gegeben hat, um in der Wikipedia zu schreiben - mehr noch: für die englischsprachige Wikipedia, welches ja andere Regeln und Sprachkulturen impliziert.

Comment: @userunknown richtig, deshalb habe ich sie hier nicht aufgezählt. Allerding sind das die Konventionen die man auch in den Medien beobachten kann. Und die Regeln die ich herausgesucht habe, sind bloß die vernünftigsten, wesentlichen Grundsätze. Eben weil es hier keine "offizellen" Regeln gibt (jedenfalls keine, dich ich finden konnte). Getreu dem Motto, German Language & **Usage**.  Ich bin natürlich für Kritik an den einzelnen Empfehlungen offen.

Comment: `Die Hersteller haben oftmals Hinweise, wie man ihre Marke behandeln soll` klingt auch affirmativ, als wolltest Du empfehlen, den Herstellern zu folgen. Wieso sollte man das tun? Anführungszeichen zu verwenden, um am Satzanfang die Marke falsch zu schreiben - ich denke Anführungszeichen markieren direkte Rede. Ich bin doch nicht gezwungen irgendwelche Produkte wie Heiligkeiten zu behandeln, für die Sonderregeln gelten, die sich irgendwelche Produzenten ausgedacht haben! Ist ja nicht meine Schuld, wenn die Ihr Produkt *iPhone* nennen.

Comment: Wenn dich das iPhone stört, kannst du auch die andere Möglichkeit nutzen: `Das Iphone (eigene schreibweise: iPhone), ...`, das steht dir frei. Allerding kommt es mir doch etwas ungeschickt vor, gerade wenn die Schreibweise nicht allzu fremdartig ist. Zu den Hinweisen vom Hersteller: Das war mehr dazu gedacht, nachzuschlagen, wenn man sich nicht sicher ist. Dazu sind diese Nutzungshinweise doch sehr hilfreich. Man muss sich aber, in der tat, oftmals daran halten, wenn man mit den Firmen zusammenarbeiten will (vgl.: "Android™ anwendung").

Comment: Das man Vertreter der Firma deren Konventionen berücksichtigen muss - das ist ja nun trivial. Und geh' mir weg mit dem TM- meine Tastatur hat das nicht! :) Einen literarischen Text, der von einem `iPhone` handelt, würde ich als Werbung betrachten. Der nächste besorgt sich die Klötzchen, die die Telekom verwendet, und garniert damit seine Texte, und erklärt es für verbindlich.

Comment: Du hast schon Recht. Deshalb sage ich ja: benutzt' dein eigenes Einschätzungsvermögen wenn du dich zwischen "mArKe" und "Marke (mArKe)" entscheiden musst. Ledeglich gegen *konsequentes* "falsch"-schreiben (MAC, Iphone, Gogrid, ...), ohne Kontext, hab' ich dann doch etwas. Namen wie "se7en" (hä?) würde aber *selbst ich* nicht im Fließtext benutzen. :D

Answer (score 1):

Um mal auf die Ausgangsfrage einzugehen: "Woher kommt die Unsitte?"

Ich spekuliere mal, dass ein Teil der Motivation, eine Marke durchgehend in Großbuchstaben zu schreiben, sein könnte, eine prominentere Platzierung zu erreichen bzw. einfach besser aufzufallen. Ein Wort komplett in Großbuchstaben sticht aus einem normalen Satz einfach heraus. Natürlich sieht es ästhetisch meistens alles andere als schön aus, aber wie heißt es nun mal so schön: Nur keine Publicity ist schlechte Publicity.

Answer (score 0):

Hat die Dozentin denn selbst keinen Grund angeben können?

Als Spekulation: Ich könnte mir durchaus einen markenrechtlichen Hintergrund vorstellen, in dem Sinne, dass eine Marke möglichst getreu dem registrierten Entwurf wiedergegeben werden sollte. Das hieße aber natürlich nicht konsequente Komplettgroßschreibung. Also bleibt das iPhone so, wie’s sein sollte. Eine Firma, die ein eingetragenes Markenzeichen erhalten möchte, ist durchaus zur Pflege und zum Schutz verpflichtet. Das kann bedeuten, missbräuchliche und auch verfremdende Verwendungen zu ahnden. Vielleicht kommt von daher die – in meinen Augen – übertriebene und falsche Großschreibungsverpflichtung der in der Frage angesprochenen Dozentin.

Aber ich bin nicht vom (Design-)Fach.

Comment: Die Dozentin hat leider nie irgendetwas begründen können, was sie häufig durch schlechte Laune und Beleidigungen zu vertuschen versucht hat.